# How to enable proper scrolling after scrub effect in a webpage using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found a code from [codepen](https://codepen.io/ollieRogers/pen/lfeLc/) to use it for scrub effect in video. After the video has ended I want to enable complete scrolling. How can I acheive that? Thanks in advance!

```
var frameNumber = 0, // start video at frame 0
// lower numbers = faster playback
playbackConst = 500, 
// get page height from video duration
setHeight = document.getElementById("set-height"), 
// select video element         
vid = document.getElementById('v0'); 
// var vid = $('#v0')[0]; // jquery option

// dynamically set the page height according to video length
vid.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  setHeight.style.height = Math.floor(vid.duration) * playbackConst + "px";
});


// Use requestAnimationFrame for smooth playback
function scrollPlay(){  
  var frameNumber  = window.pageYOffset/playbackConst;
  vid.currentTime  = frameNumber;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
```